# crontab is not executing the commands properly

Tags: linux, cron, centos

There is a application command called 'HM17.5' which is located at `/tool/SITE/HM17.5`

What I want : I want to execute this application at every morning at 9AM with new fresh terminal. Reason behind to execute on terminal is I can see log as well if something is getting print on terminal while working in application.

Here are the few try I have given so far

---

Try 1 : `crontab -e > * * * * * HM17.5`

Error - HM17.5 command not found.

---

Try 2 : `crontab -e > * * * * * /tool/SITE/HM17.5`

Error - /tool/SITE/HM17.5 command not found.

---

Try 3 : `crontab -e > * * * * * /bin/mate-terminal --command HM17.5`

Error - /bin/sh: /bin/matte-terminal: No such file or directory

---

Try 4 : `crontab -e > * * * * * /bin/mate-terminal --command "HM17.5"`

Error - Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:

---

Try 5 : `crontab -e > * * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /bin/mate-terminal --command "HM17.5"`

Error - It opens up the terminal but throws an error HM17.5 no file or directory

Note : Exactly what I want but half done atleast it open up the new terminal but again fail to execute the command

Answer (score 0):

You can't run terminal in cron on the way you try. But if app do not need graphical interface you can run command redirecting the STDOUT and STDERR to specific logs and from those logs to monitor what happen with the execution.

For this you need to have the path to the executable file of this software. And the `cron` record will be like:

```
0 9 * * * /tool/SITE/HM17.5/your_executable_file >/path/to/log 2>/path/ro/errorlog
```

in your script you can add (after shebang something like)

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

to get the environment variables set

Comment: Thanks for correcting the code

This is what I have got in error log
bob-show-target-name: Command not found.
/tools/SITE/scripts/houdini: line 47: bob-mount: command not found

Comment: so correct your script. make all executables with full path

Comment: Under Try 2 I have already made my script executable. What I am guessing is Is it something related to environment ? not sure what exactly causing the error.

Comment: @mehulJ, add in to the begin of your script line like `source ~/.bashrc` this should correct the environment things

Comment: So if I add .mycshrc as shebang it gave me output in log file saying all aliases and env are not found.

Comment: @mehulJ, no instead of shebang, AFTER the shebang

Comment: (#!/bin/python \n source ~/.mycshrc \n full path of command )am I still doing something wrong ? Cuz this is giving me syntax error on “.mycshrc”

Comment: @mehulJ, if its python create wrapper bash (or csh) script where you put this source command

Comment: sorry for late replying but later on find out there is a different config to do that as company has modified to their own way and native method doesn't work in their system.